# What is the best way to give users a printer-friendly page option?

Tags: asp.net, css, printing, stylesheet

My site is in asp.net 4 / vb.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to make a printer-friendly page that only includes our logo at the top and pertinent information, but omits things like navigational bars and other things that aren't necessary.  I have a click-to-print icon and it works fine in all browsers, but it doesn't always print out printer-friendly.

I've read things on this site about making a print.css stylesheet, but I'm unsure as to how I'd code the stylesheet, or if I have to assign div attributes to things I want omitted -- and the posts were older posts.  Is it recommended that I omit the navigational links, etc., and if so, what is the best way to go about doing this?  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS `@media` types.

```
<p> this should be part of the printed page </p>

<div id="navigation_bar_that_should_not_be printed" class="noprint">.....</div>
```

A simplistic style sheet for the above would be:

```
@media screen
{
   /* whatever styles you have for display */
}

@media print
{
   .noprint { display: none; }
}
```

In the above, the `<div>` with the `class="noprint"` will be displayed on screen as usual, but it will not be printed.

---

Update:

The "C" in `CSS` stands for "cascading" - meaning the "last" or closest instruction wins. I can only assume that the `<span class="bodycontent"...` (being the *last or closest*) is overriding the div.

ASP.Net Controls have a `CssClass` property, that's how you'd define it:

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com" runat="server" CssClass="noprint" Text="foo" />
```

You can even directly type `class="noprint"` (instead of using CssClass) in any ASP.Net tag - VS may complain but it should be ok:

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com" runat="server" class="noprint" Text="foo" />
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, EdSF.  In my head at the top of my products.master, I have     <link href="../styles/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />  |  In my print.css, I have @media print
{
   .noprint { display: none; }
}                                          | Finally, as an experiment, I wrapped div tags around "other exclusive products", because I don't know how to put a class inside an asp:hyperlink tag, so it looks like this (see next comment):

Comment: <div class="noprint">
<span class="bodycontent">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink20" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl="~/products/" Target="_self" meta:resourcekey="HyperLink20Resource1" Text="Other Exclusive 

Products"></asp:HyperLink></span>
</div>            ....................................  "Other Exclusive Products" shows up on the web, but it also shows up when printing.  But again, I'm still learning about css's and I truly do appreciate you taking the time to help -- I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually!

Comment: Success!  I got rid of the side navigational menu when printing, as well as some other things.  The only thing I'm having trouble with is the top navigational menu now.  If I put div tags around it, it shows up on the web in a strange way.  It looks like this:                  <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                    EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    meta:resourcekey="NavigationMenuResource1">
                    <Items> etc., etc., and then I have a bunch of <asp:MenuItems> ... Thank you!

Comment: @JasonWeber You can define multiple classes for an element. Try `CssClass="menu noprint"` for your `asp:Menu` control

Comment: Yes, I used that in some instances, @EdSF ... however, in other instances, the CssClass within an asp: tag gave me a 500 error, so I had to use either div or span tags.  At any rate, things are working perfectly now -- all 5 master pages are updated with the noprint stylesheet, so I thank you and everyone else who took the time to help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to actually add additional elements to wrap stuff that you don't want to show when printing. The best way to do a print stylesheet is to apply a class (maybe call it `print_hide`) on elements you want to hide when your page is printed. For example:

```
<div>Text</div>
<img class='print_hide' src='some_huge_image.png'/>
```

In your print.css stylesheet, you would do:

```
.print_hide {
    display: none;
}
```

To apply the stylesheet, add this to your `head`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

The `div` would still print, but the image would not.

This is, of course, in addition to whatever other style changes you want, like removing background images, changing colors, fonts, etc.

Adding that class to stuff to hide at print is a relatively minimal change to existing code.

The other option is to create a separate printer friendly version of all of your pages, and if your pages are really complicated, this might be the way to do it. That being said, the benefit of print.css (in addition to being less work) is that users don't need to explicitly select `Printer friendly version`, of course.

Comment: Hey SimpleCoder, thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed explanation on how to go about doing that.  I think I got the hang of it, but I'm still working out the details.  For now, when I put  class="print_hide" after a tr or whatever, it makes it disappear completely ... even from web view ... hehe.  But you definitely put me on the right track, and I truly appreciate you taking the time to offer a thoughtful response.

Comment: @JasonWeber: You're welcome! `print.css` should have been applied with a style tag that has a `media` attribute set to `print`; I forgot to add this, my bad. That would have made it worked. (see my edit)

Comment: Yes, I did have media is set to print ... that's one thing I actually did right ... lol.  Thanks for the tip, @simplecoder, and I'll get this to work -- I'm almost there, just trying to make it look good in all browsers.  IE, as usual, is a pain.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think the main problem is that I already have classes within a lot of these things, so extra classes I want to add (class="noprint", CssClass="noprint"), I have to use div tags.  And when I try to keep then on one line by using the css property display:inline, then the noprint doesn't work!  When I use float:left, the noprint works, but it looks different in different browsers (especially IE).  I'll just keep doing trial and error and hopefully, with your help and the help others have given me, one of these will finally work -- both on the web and when printing.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Solved!  I used my noprint class in a span tag, and I used my smallprint class in the div tags -- success!  I definitely appreciate the time you've spent in helping me!